# How to handle my sms statuscallback in twilio using .net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api

this is my api url call from my application:

```
statusCallback: new Uri("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/api/SMSAPI"/>
```

this is what i tried in my API:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        string MessageStatus="From Body: " + value;
        //return statusText;
        printLog(MessageStatus);

    }
```

where printLog() writes data in log file.
but the problem is it prints only "From Body:" so how to get all values from twilio

Also it gives error 500 in twilio console...
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrzDJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Twilio passes parameters as form encoded values, so you can specify the names of those [individual parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#request-parameters) as your method parameters to let ASP.NET automatically map them:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string To, [FromBody]string From, [FromBody]string Body)
```

Or you can use the [twilio-aspnet](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-aspnet) Nuget package to map them all into a single strongly typed object:

```
public void Post(SmsRequest request)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: when im giving more than one parameter, method does not even hitting
but when i gives a single paramter like ```public void Post([FromBody]string To)```
method gets hit but still no value appears